# Unable to get dynamic sum of the column values using Angular

Tags: jquery, angular

Trying to get select all records on current page and count the amounts dynamically. Tried below code, I'm able to select records but unable to found the dynamic count(individually selects getting count, but if we select all I'm not getting the count). Please help me on this issue.

```
checkuncheckall() {
    let chkBoxlength = $(".checkboxCls:checked").length;
    if (this.isChecked == true) {
      $(".checkboxCls").prop("checked", false);
      this.isChecked = false;
    } else {
      $(".checkboxCls").prop("checked", true);
      this.isChecked = true;
    }
    this.checkboxCheckCount();
    
    // const totalChecked = this.persons.filter(f => f.checked).length;
    // const target = totalChecked !== this.persons.length;
    // this.persons.forEach(f => (f.checked = target));
    // this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-current-page)

Comment: Made a few changes to your [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-current-page-mqqeya?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) check it out

Comment: Thanks @Bargos for reply, please help me is there any way to get records only current (visible) page instead of all page records

Comment: you mean the records currently visible in the page? well I'd say, sort the array in either desc or asc order (you actually don't have to, it'll still be the first 10 records eitherway), you can find out which records are being displayed because the table is paginated, if you know which page and the amount displayed per page, then you can easily get the records from the array, for example, if you sort it in asc order and you're on the first page and the page displays only 10 records, then you know is displaying records 0-9 of the array, page 2 -> 10-19, etc...

Comment: Some advice for you mate, don't use JQuery and weird elements from 3rd party libraries in Angular 2+, use [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/), so you don't run into such issues in the future. Don't use a 3rd party unless you really have to and that happens very rarely. Also I believe I resolved your check/uncheck issue in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using jquery in this case. Just change your `checkuncheckall` function to:

```
checkuncheckall() {
  this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
  this.persons.forEach(f => (f.checked = this.isChecked));
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-current-page-brnhto?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks @Cuong Le Ngoc for reply, please help me is there any way to get records only current (visible) page instead of all page records

Comment: I've made some modify to solve that. Please check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-current-page-b2bxw3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Filter scenario is nor working, if we filter in text box like Toto, superman and apply a select all, only few records are selected and remaining are not selected and data is not updated. used console.log(this.persons.filter(f => f.checked).map(m => m.id).length); for getting count of checkboxes selected.

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-current-page-tgegfk?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Yes,now its updating filters as well. thank you very much @Cuong Le Ngoc.

Comment: HI @Coung Le Ngoc, I stuck this issue, it would be very great help 
 if you answer this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633940/unbale-to-pass-params-to-the-api-getting-undefined