# Unable to pass params to the API, getting undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatables, angular-datatables

Trying to pass params to the API for loading the datatable, but getting undefined. I tried below code, could you please suggest me if any issues.

```
loadTable(){
      let self = this;
      this.dtOptions = {
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        pageLength: 10,
        drawCallback: function() {           
          var api = this.api();
          pageInfo = api.page.info();
          pgno = pageInfo.page + 1;
          pageEnd = pageInfo.end;           
        }
      };

     this.http.get("/api/testAPI?param1=111&param2=222&param3=333&pageMinRow="+info .start+"&pageMaxRow="+info .end)
       .subscribe((res:any) => {
             this.results = res.data;
             this.dtTrigger1.next();
    });
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatable-server-side-nctyv2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: `pageInfo` is set to `{}` when you call `http.get`, probably because `drawCallback` is called after the `http` request. You should have datatable instance in some variable, to have access to its properties

Comment: also you can specify url in `ajax` property of dtOptions, see [doc](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/with-ajax)

Comment: HI @Filip Kováč, tried dataTable instance stored in a variable and passed to a API, still have issue. If possible could you please provide sample code ?Latest changes updated in the above question..

Comment: Added stackblitz demo for reference in the question

Comment: As i wrote before, check the docs. You are looking for server side processing datatable. Anyway you dtOptions should be instantioned just once on init of component, not every time you want to reload table.